# Refreshing page to anchor tag that is generated dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to `Redirect_to();` an anchor tag when someone makes a blog post.  When the post is submitted there is a bunch of code that is fired in my Blog class -> `submitPost()` then this is generated:

```
Redirect_to("fullpost.php?id={$PostIDFromURL}#{$just_posted_id}");
```

It works.  Once submitted the page URL that I'm reloading contains both variables.  ex. (`http://localhost/SOMESITE/fullpost.php?id=59#115`)

The #115 should reload the page at that anchored location.

When the posts are loaded in my Blog class -> `loadBlogPosts()` is fired resulting in the following return:

```
$str .= "<div class='pw-box comment-list'>
           <div class='comment-item'>
           <a name='$id' id='$id'></a>
           <div class='comment-pic round-pic'>
            <img src='$profile_pic'>
          </div>
```

The above is not the entirety, but you can see that an `<a>` tag is generated with the name and id of `$id`.  When I inspect this, it definitely returns the corresponding id value.  ex. `<a name="115" id="115></a>`.  So what's the problem? It's not reloading at the anchor tag. It just reloads to the top of the page.

Is this because the  tags are created dynamically?

When I change out this:
 `Redirect_to("fullpost.php?id={$PostIDFromURL}#{$just_posted_id}");`

for this `Redirect_to("fullpost.php?id={$PostIDFromURL}#refresh");` and then add `<a name="refresh" id="refresh></a>` on the page (one time) it works.

I'm just puzzled as to why the dynamically generated anchor tags are not working.

Any help/thoughts appreciated!

Comment: header("Location: fullpost.php?id={$PostIDFromURL}#{$just_posted_id}"); Can you try this one?

Comment: is the generated id unique to only one div?

Comment: @Dimitris Filippou.  yes, that id is unique to only that post, so only possible that one div will have it.

Comment: @J Quest.  Exact same result.  The URL is the same, contains the `#id` but still reloads at the top.

Comment: Something I noticed.  When I inspect the specific post `div`, it is there with the correct anchor tag.  When I View the source code, it's not there (none of the posts are) only the `div` where the dynamic posts are dropped into.  So is it fair to say that I'm not able to do this?

Comment: @Gigi, when you "view source" you will not see the dynamic additions. Only what the server sent initially to the browser. If you can see them using "inspect" then they are there.

Comment: I see, thanks @Mr Glass.  Any thoughts on why they aren't picking up in the reload?  If they're on page and unique to one `div`, theoretically it should work.

Comment: @Gigi, I'm not sure. I just tested this by adding a tag to a page and it worked. is it possible that id you added to the `<a>` tag and `$just_posted_id` have different values?

Comment: @ Mr Glass.  not that I can see.  The URL has #115 and the `<a>` tag has an name and id of 115.  The next post would be #116 and the corresponding  `<a>` tag with name and id of 116 etc.  It's not possible for another `<div>` to have the same id, and  `$just_posted_id` to not correspond.

Comment: Could it be that the post is submitted (then the reload occurs here) and right after the post are loaded, where the anchor tags are then created.  It happens in a flash, but may be the problem I'm not sure.